# Iterate through a string that's on an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, character

I have a code like this:

```
char* s[4][10] = { "abc\0", "aab\0", "cbb\0" };
```

a want to type a character, like..  'a', and iterate through the array of strings, check on each string if there's 'a' on it, and then count how many there's on it..

In this case, what I wanted to get is `"abc" : 1`, `"aab" : 2`, `"cbb" : 0` ...
how can I do the loops to get this result?

Comment: And what is the problem with your code, id doesn't find the `a`'s? and you don't need the `'\0'` it's implied.

Comment: stackoverflow != do my home work for me. Please post your attempt and describe any specifc problems you encountered and someone may be able to help you.

Comment: Alvaro, get rid of the explicit nulls in your string literals - string literals have implicit nulls and thus "abc\0" is FIVE characters long.

Comment: just to let you know, i didn't ask to do my homework, just solve something a I couldn't

Answer (score 0):

```
char input = '\0';
scanf("%c", &input);
int i, j;
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
         if(s[i][j] == input) count++;
    }
    printf("%s : %d", s[i], count);
}
```

although please note, that simply copying and pasting will not teach you anything.

Comment: Why provide the answer at all? That just encourages these kinds of questions.

Comment: The problem is fairly elementary, so I guess it won't hurt that much, although in principle you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how you can deal with different declarations of arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char* s[4][10] = { { "abc", "aab", "cbb" } };

    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
        {
            if ( s[i][j] )
            {
                size_t count = 0;
                for ( char *p = s[i][j]; *p != '\0'; ++p )
                {
                    if ( *p == 'a' ) ++count;
                }

                printf( "\"%s\": %zu\n", s[i][j], count );
            }
        }
    }

    printf( "\n" );

    char* t[4] = { "abc", "aab", "cbb" };

    for ( char **p = t; *p != NULL; ++p )
    {
        size_t count = 0;

        for ( char *q = *p; *q != '\0'; ++q )
        {
            if ( *q == 'a' ) ++count;
        }

        printf( "\"%s\": %zu\n", *p, count );
    }


    printf( "\n" );

    char u[4][10] = { "abc", "aab", "cbb" };

    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        if ( u[i][0] != '\0' )
        {
            size_t count = 0;
            for ( char *p = u[i]; *p != '\0'; ++p )
            {
                if ( *p == 'a' ) ++count;
            }

            printf( "\"%s\": %zu\n", u[i], count );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"abc": 1
"aab": 2
"cbb": 0

"abc": 1
"aab": 2
"cbb": 0

"abc": 1
"aab": 2
"cbb": 0
```

It seems that you mean either the second variant of the array declaration or the third variant of the array declaration. The first variant looks strange.:)

Take into account that string literals already contain terminating zero. So there is no sense to write, for example

```
"abc\0"
```

It is enough to write simply

```
"abc"
```

The `sizeof( "abc" )` is equal to 4 due to the presence of the terminating zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char s[10][4] = { "abc", "aab", "cbb" };
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i != sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0]); i++) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%zu: %s\n", i, s[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *s[4] = { "abc", "aab", "cbb" };
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i != 3; i++) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%zu: %s\n", i, s[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the original declaration

```
char* s[4][10] = { "abc\0", "aab\0", "cbb\0" };
```

had several errors:

- `char *` instead of `char`
- `[4][10]` instead of `[10][4]`
- `"abc\0"` instead of `"abc"` (the trailing `'\0'` is implicit).